# What does "workhouses" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Molly's Game* (2017), former skier Molly meets her psychiatrist father after a long time at ice rink:

> Molly: I wasn't asking for money when I called you, Dad. I just needed
> my dad. God forbid you part with a nickel.
>
> Father: Yeah, Tiny Tim, you grew up on a lake and you've skied all
> over the world. Were those **workhouses** tough?

What does "workhouses" mean?
I am thinking her father is making a sarcastic remark by suggesting that the
experiences of her daughter, who grew up skiing, were similar to those of
people who lived in workhouses.

Comment: As part of the sarcastic response to his spoiled child, it means "shelters for the homeless".

Comment: I know nothing of the story, but Tiny Tim is a well-known Dickens character, the disabled youngest child of a poor family, so presumably the reference is indeed to Victorian workhouses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sarcasm.

[Tiny Tim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Tim_(A_Christmas_Carol)) is character from Dicken's *A Christmas Carol*, he is the disabled and underweight son of Scrooge's underpaid clerk.

Workhouses were a feature of Victorian Britain. A person who could not find normal paid work would be housed in a "[workhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workhouse)" and required to work for food and a bed.

Molly is complaining that her father never gave her money. The father is using sarcasm to suggest that the daughter had a privileged upbringing - she had money and opportunities. She never lived in a workhouse.